# WPF ListBox Aynchronous Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box that performs auto-complete feature which populates dynamically. The listbox displays a list of names with the employee's picture. I find that populating data with image slow.

I would like to be able to populate the names first and then upload the data asynchronously as and when it is received. How do I go about doing so?

My Image class code at the moment:

```
public class Img : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private Image image;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Img(string name, Image image)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
        }
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The code that populates the data:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in items)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Image webImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            webImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (ThreadStart)delegate
                {

                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.BeginInit();
                    image.UriSource = new Uri(//Where the source is);
                    image.EndInit();

                    webImage.Source = image;
                });
            myListBox.Items.Add(new Img(entry.Value, webImage));
        }
```

My XAML code:

```
<Popup Name="myPopUp">
    <ListBox Name="myListBox" FontSize="14">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Img}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="3" Content="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name, IsAsync=True}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

At the moment, it populates all the names + images at the same time...which causes the listbox to be unbearably slow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK there are two things you are missing for the lazy loading of images to work....

1. `PriorityBinding` in the order of slow loading and then fast loading imagesources.
2. `DownloadCompleted` event of each image must notify changes to the binding that it is ready to display.

See these two posts and see if you can get a hint...

[How to lazy load image byte[] into a WPF image control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057240/how-to-lazy-load-image-byte-into-a-wpf-image-control)

[initial image in WPF Image Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973629/initial-image-in-wpf-image-control)

Let me know if this helps.